# Changed some chars on a Private key, and JWT still authenticates

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jwt

I have implemented JWT in order to authenticate on Google cloud, as described in https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#jwt-auth

To my surprise, I've noticed that I could change some chars on the private key, and it would still authenticate. Changing chars in some places didn't work, and I got `OpenSSL unable to sign data` from the PHP JWT library. And some other places resulted in access being denied. But for example, when I changed a char in this line - it authenticated well.

[image]

How can that be? That is, I don't think it's possible to change any char on the private key and get it to work. But that's what I see on my local and when checked via GitPod. So I'm wondering what I might be missing.

Here's an example PHP code:

```php
<?php

include_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use Symfony\Component\HttpClient\HttpClient;

$privateKey = <<<EOD
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

EOD;

$payload = [
  'iss' => "bar@foo.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  'sub'=> "bar@foo.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  'aud'=> "https://healthcare.googleapis.com/",
  'iat' => time(),
  'exp' => time() + 3600,
];

$jwt = JWT::encode($payload, $privateKey, 'RS256');

$client = HttpClient::create();
$url = 'https://healthcare.googleapis.com/v1/projects/foo/locations/us-central1/datasets/my-dataset/fhirStores/my-fhir-store/fhir/Patient';

$patientIdentifier = 'Some-name' . time();

$response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
  'headers' => [
    'Content-Type' => 'application/fhir+json',
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $jwt,
  ],
  'json' => [
    'resourceType' => 'Patient',
    'name' => [
      0 => [
        'family' => 'Migo',
        'given' => [
          0 => 'Dada',
        ],
      ],
    ],
    'gender' => 'male',
    'birthDate' => '1980-09-24',
  ],
]);

echo $response->getContent();
```

Here is a [short video](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/125707/172363004-3d395992-07bd-4304-b6d4-eef4ea333a92.mp4) showing the problem I face. I've run it on GitPod, just to be sure it doesn't have my credentials anywhere on it. In the video you can see:

1. 1st execution with the un-altered private key - works well
2. 2nd execution with an altered private key - Still works (and obviously it shouldn't)
3. 3rd execution, undo the previous change, and alter the private key elsewhere - now I get 401.

p.s. I've already changed the private key, so the one here is no longer valid :)

Comment: It's not really clear what you did and what happened. You write about *authentication*, but that happens usually before the JWT is issued. So you just tell us that you changed the private key and it could still be used to sign a token, right? But when you use that JWT in a later call to your API, the JWT would not be validated with the original public key, unless you created a new public key from the modified private key. And in the error case it seems the key was invalid after your modification and then after authentication the JWT could not be created and the program logic then sent a 401.

Comment: ... Let us know if my above assumption is right and edit your question to clarify. But then the title *JWT still authenticates* would be misleading, as it is not a problem of JWT doing something unexpected, but just a key that is still valid after your modification.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the questions with the code, a clearer question: the private key can't be changed and work - so what am I missing, that I see as if it does :)

Answer (score 1):

I understand, hashing, signing, private keys, etc very well. Your claim is impossible mathematically. Any change to the private key will result in a different hash which means the public key will no longer work to validate the signature. That form of weakness would have been discovered long ago. Private/public key validation cannot be manipulated by changing the values in one of the keys without changing the other.

One minor point is that the private key is base-64 encoded. You would need to replace those characters with valid base-64 data, which you might have done, but you did not explain in detail what you changed.

Perhaps edit your question with actual code to demonstrate. Give this some thought, if you can demonstrate this, you will be a millionaire next week or at least famous worldwide.

Comment: Thanks, indeed. I've edited the question to make it clearer. I don't think it's possible to change the private key, and get it to work. So wondering what I might be missing?

Comment: @amitaibu - Your JWT is not even created correctly. You have included the payload section but have not included the header section. An RSA key is two prime numbers. The odds of you being able to randomly modify the private key which is a large prime number (512, 1024, 2048,  or 4096 bits) and still have a prime number is astronomically low. Therefore, your assumption that you have modified a private key and **are** using that private key successfully is impossible.

Comment: THe JWT header is added by the library inside `JWT::encode`. Anyway, I'll keep digging, to see what's going on, as indeed it doesn't make sense it succeeds - so it must be something else.

Comment: @amitaibu Your assumption is incorrect. Google needs the **kid** set so that it knows how to look up the public key for the signature. The library does not know what that value is.

Comment: I see. Then surely something else is authorizing my calls, since I didn't pass the `kid`, and requests pass as valid. What's weird, is that I'm sure the service account is used, because when I disable it, or when I pass a different private key - I get 401.

But still not sure what..

Comment: I've updated the question with a link to a video showing what I see.